# SharePoint Approval doesn't send the user to the approval page, It send's the user to the task page that is linked to the approval page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow, approval

I have currently created a workflow that does the following;

- Awaits for a column value to change and then starts this workflow.
- Starts an approval on the current item in the sharepoint task list that changed  and then sends the details to the assigned to user.

My problem is I can't find a Lookup that will allow me to pass the approval page (page with approve / reject buttons) directly. I see in other questions people use have used the FORM_URN lookup, I don't seem to have access to that ?

I am using SharePoint designer 2013.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 approval task by default will send mail with the task details. On clicking the hyperlink in the email, will take us to the task item in view form and then we have to click edit item to open the approve/reject item page. Its by design, but where as in SharePoint 2010 type workflows - approval task - will send email with option "Open This Task", on click of it, approve/reject page opens. "FORM_URN" this for SharePoint 2010 type workflow item.